# How change Background Color of datagridview rows in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, datagridview

I tried this code but didn't work correctly :(

please help me :)

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1)
   row.DefultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: `foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) { ... }`

Comment: _didn't work correctly_ is not a helpful problem secription. in fact i would expect to see a compiler wanring, no??

Comment: BackgroundColor didn't change, this is my problem :))

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: a) the code you show makes no sense and should not compile. See comment1!! b) Where exactly is the code located and when does it run? Are the rows already in place?? c) if you set e.g. cell colors these will take precedence. d) As always: Do use the debugger to find out if the line is called and what the values are before and after. Never ask a question here before asking the debugger!!